# How to style bootstrap dropdown button with table?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I am attempting to style a table within a dropdown button.

```html
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion" data-target="#demo2" aria-expanded="true">Supported Tenders</button>
      <div id="demo2" class="out collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
         <br>
         <table table-hover="">
               <tr>
                  <td>Account Type URI: Account</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Network Type URI: Network</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Onboarding Tender: Discover</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Onboarding Gateway: MCX</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Attribute Name: New</td> <tr>
                  </tr><td>Attribute Value: Tender</td>
               </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Essentially,
1. I am wondering how I can move "Attribute Name" and "Attribute Value" to the next column.

2. Is there any way to create a panel or something that shrinks/collapses the table?

Any assistance will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>table collapsed in this button click for view the table</h3>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Supported Tenders</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
     <table table-hover="">
               <tr>
                  <td>Account Type URI: Account</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Network Type URI: Network</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Onboarding Tender: Discover</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Onboarding Gateway: MCX</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Attribute Name: New</td> 
                  <td>Attribute Value: Tender</td>
               </tr>
         </table>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I apologize. I did not phrase my question appropriately. I am aware of the script plugins. I was looking to create another collapsible bar within the Supported Tenders dropdown and move Attribute Name and Attribute value to the next column stacked on top of each other.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/fdTMNTiLis check this link there is differen type of nested table collapsible.

Comment: Yup I used exactly that example to figure it out. Thanks!